# Are Landsat version tags justified?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need individual tags for each Landsat version? Currently we have the generic [landsat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landsat) (104) as well as [landsat-5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landsat-5) (2), [landsat-7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landsat-7) (8), and [landsat-8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landsat-8) (34).

Certainly the version can have an impact on the question since the available bands, resolutions, formats, and time frames are going to vary. But is that actually *tag* worthy, or should it just be stated in the question body? I note quite a few questions with two or even three of these tags, which seems like an awful lot of redundancy. For example questions usually aren't tagged with both versions of a software when asking about differences/changes, just the most current.

If consensus is they stay and are justified, some Wiki cleanup is in order.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's justified. If we compare to the arcgis and qgis tags, we have `arcgis-10.0` and `arcgis-10.1` etc, and `qgis`,`qgis-2.0`, `qgis-2.2` etc. So the same rule should be applied to `landsat` and `landsat-8` etc. If the user uses redundant tags it should be edited, otherwise, I think the differences between the different satellites do require a unique tag for each.